# Using angular function binding inside .html() in d3

Tags: angular, d3.js

I want to make a d3 foreignObject span clickable such that clicking on it calls a function in the component TS file. Here is a snippet of the code that I have tried:

```
.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y)
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .html(function (d) {
    return `<span (click)="someAngularFunction()"> ClickMe!</span>`
  })
```

Anyone know how I can get this to work? I am using Angular 11 and d3v6.5.

Edited:
Please see the accepted response for how to get this to work.

Also, you might have to do this

```
let that=this
... 
.on("click", function (element) {that.someAngularFunction(element.target.innerText)})
```

to get access to the function inside D3 scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use any Angular templating inside this piece of html.

You need to use d3 to setup the event handler for click.

```js
.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", x)
  .attr("y", y)
  .append("xhtml:body")
  .html(function (d) {
    return `<span> ClickMe!</span>`
  })
  .on("click", () => this.someAngularFunction())
```